# In Python, is it better to have two parameters for different types of the same thing, or handle one parameter of multiple types?

Tags: python

Please help resolve this debate on my team:

If we have a function that takes either a point (list of 3 values) or a list of points, then we have either:

```
def f(point=None, points=None):
    if points is None: points = []
    if point is not None: points.append(point)
    .... stuff with "points" ....
```

or

```
def g(points):
    if len(points) > 0 and not isinstance(points[0],list):
        points = [points]
    .... stuff with "points" ....
```

to be called as,

```
x = f(points=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
y = f(point=[1,2,3])
z = g(points=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
w = g(points=[1,2,3])
```

where x,y,z, and w should all be the same (if f and g are the same function).

That is to say, internally both `f` and `g` want a 2-dimensional array, but provide mechanisms to accept a single-dimensional array.

The difference is that `f` has an argument for each type, and therefore each argument expects a single, specific type, but `g` has a single argument that may be of multiple types.

The question is, which style is more "Pythonic"?  (References to PEPs more than welcome.. I couldn't find anything.)

Edit: I forgot to mention that ostensibly the reason for supporting 1-dimensional input is backwards compatibility.  That is to say, `f(point, axis)` already exists, and we are changing it to `f(points, axes)`.. and we are trying to changing the callers as they are external to this code base.  I agree that perhaps the right answer is to *not* do this at all and force the caller to be consistent with their types, but I ask the reader to assume this would be difficult and to provide some clarity on the two choices I am asking about, if at all possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this might be a lot easier to solve on the caller's side…? `f([point])`? Or is the caller typically equally in the dark about whether they're dealing with a list or a single point?

Comment: In general, if the datatypes are easily distinguishable I'd go for flexible functions. If the type in either case is a `list`, I'd skip the possible ambiguity and force the caller to provide one kind of argument.

Comment: You make a good point, and perhaps it is the right answer, but I have updated the question to clarify that the reason for supporting 1-dimensional input is for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'd argue it's better to have only one input format, to test it and to document it than to be too flexible in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the signatures of your `f` and `g` differ, I'm assuming you control how the function is or will be called. In this case, the most logical thing to do would be to accept only two dimensional lists and call it like this:

```
x = h([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
y = h([[1,2,3]])
```

A list of points with only one element is no special case unless it is semantically diferent than a multipoint list in your context or it would change the functions behavior.

Comment: Of course `f` and `g` don't exist in the actual code, they are just examples of how we are thinking of changing a certain function.  We were trying to preserve backward compatibility, but the discussion here convinced me it's not worth it, so we ended up doing what you suggest here, which is to convert to only accept 2-dimensional lists and change *all* call sites.  It was a rather more work but perhaps better in the end.  It's a user-facing function however, so hopefully we didn't break too much code external to our code base.

Comment: Indeed it seems like the best option, after the pain of touching all call sites you'll end up with a cleaner solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest **using *args** (or, well, call it *points possibly) and making the user unpack his points on his end.

This allows you to call **f(point)**, **f(point1, point2, point3)**, or **f(*list_of_points)**, with all three options working fine and you can simply do:

```
def f(*points):
    ...
    for point in points:
        do_pointy_stuff(point)
```

...which is similar to g2 but without hacky **isinstance** checks which would fail if someone decided to throw in a tuple or something instead.

However, there is a minor potential pitfall here - the user must knowingly unpack his lists of points. If you don't pay attention when using a single argument, you may pass a *[points] rather than a *[[list of points]], which would result in the function treating each coordinate as a separate argument in itself and most likely throwing an error.

Comment: Ah, that is an interesting approach, but in my case f() may have more than one argument like this, which of course I didn't think of mentioning in the question.. ;)  Thanks!

Comment: This is good. You get the best of both worlds: it's clear how you need to call the function and you don't need any extra logic inside the function.